# Process PowerShell Jobs As And When They Finish

Tags: powershell, jobs

I am currently run a PowerShell job on 50 servers to obtain data like CPU and Memory and a few other metrics

Once the start-job part of the script is finished, I then use receive-job to get the data. Everything is working. However, sometimes, a server can take time to respond and finish the job. This can delay the process data part of the script.
Is there a way to receive a job when its finished, instead of going through a list of servers and waiting for the job to finish?
For example, server 5 finishes first, so the process the data on server 5, then Server 10 finishes, then server 1 finishes etc....

Here is my script

```
$functions = {
    Function CheckCpuUsage($server) {
        $CpuUsage = #Get CPU Usage
        return $CpuUsage } 

    Function CheckMemoryUsage($server) {
            $RAMPercentUsed = #Get RAM Usage
            return $RAMPercentUsed
#functions to get other stuff
        }
#Get Data
$servers | foreach {
  $server = $_
  Start-Job -Name $server -InitializationScript $functions -ScriptBlock { Param($server)
        $arr = @()
        $CpuUsage = CheckCpuUsage $server
        $RAMPercentUsed = CheckMemoryUsage $server

            $arr += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            "CpuUsage"        = $CpuUsage
            "RAMPercentUsed"  = $RAMPercentUsed
            }

        return $arr
    } -ArgumentList $server
}

#Process Data

$servers | foreach {
  $server = $_       

    Wait-Job -Name $server
    $serverdata = Receive-Job -name $server

    $MemUsg = $serverdata.RAMPercentUsed
    $CPUUsg = $serverdata.CpuUsage  
    
    $output += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            "Server"          = $Server
            "CpuUsage"        = $CpuUsage
            "RAMPercentUsed"  = $RAMPercentUsed
            }
}
```

Comment: take a look at the `Wait-Job` cmdlet. however, a better solution is to use `Invoke-Command`, a scriptblock, and a list of systems to run the code _on the target systems_. that will offload the work to the targets AND run the code in parallel. [*grin*]

Comment: As suggested by @Lee_Dailey, I moved to Invoke-Command. script runs a lot quicker now. Thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to know that you got things working as needed ... [*grin*]